# combinatorics select sport teams

Tags: combinatorics

Problem:

There are $12$ players in a sport. In how many ways can those students be partitioned into teams A, B and C such that the team size is $4$ students.

Answer:

There was some confusion about this between my teacher and me. I was left a bit unsure, but Grimaldi's discrete math textbook does present a similar problem with example answer also...

1.) My original answer is:
$C(12,4) \cdot C(8,4) \cdot C(4,4) = 34650$

2.) My teacher thinks that the answer should be divided by ($3! = 6$)

3.) Grimaldi himself (the mathematician, author) apparently seems to think that it doesn't have to be divided by anything.

Grimaldi's book has similar problem written as "There are $36$ girls in volleyball P.E. class, and the teacher must divide the girls to teams of $9$. In how many ways can the teacher select teams A,B,C,D"
Grimaldi's answer $= C(36,9) \cdot C(27,9) \cdot C(18,9)  \cdot C(9,9)$
 No division required!?!?!

This is some funky mathematics going on in here!

Comment: It's just a question of reading.  Are the teams distinguished?  If I swap the members of teams $A,B$ have I changed the assignment or not?

Comment: For what it's worth:  personally, I'd say that since the teams are named then the teams are distinguished so swapping the members of teams $A,B$ does change the assignment.  But this is a semantics question, not a math question.

Comment: so if we made the question into clearer problem... Let's assign the people into groups of four, but teamA performs tennis, teamB performs badminton, teamC performs Squash

Comment: Exactly.  In that case the teams are clearly distinguished so there'd be no division by $3!$.

Comment: So, if the problem was that there is the school that has three teams going to different venues/tournaments, and the school selects three teams A, B and C . Then I would imagine that  there is no divisoin by six either?

Comment: but with three arbitrary teams, you would divide by six I would imagine?

Comment: Right.  If it's a gym class, and it's going to be divided into three teams that will play against each other, all that matters its what kids play on the same team, so we divide by $6$.

Comment: I think you've got it.  On the other side, if I just said "divide the kids up into groups of $4$" then I think the implication would be that swapping two groups made no difference so you would divide by $6$.

Comment: Your institutor says that because he thinks the teams are not different, like any 3 arbitrary unnamed teams, but if teams bear different labels you'd be right in that case.